# Dell Inspiron 15 5100 won't recognize SD Card

Tags: windows-10, sd-card, dell-inspiron

I have a brand-new Dell Inspiron 15 5100 running Windows 10 that I have been using for about a month. Today I was using the SD Card perfectly fine, although it ejected randomly twice. I left for 2 1/2 hours and came home to find my computer wasn't recognizing the SD Card that I paid quite some money for. I tried a chkdsk and inserted another SD Card, and the other SD Cards worked fine, it was just a 128GB SD Card that wouldn't show up on Device Manager, diskpart's list disk, or the File Explorer window. How can I fix this so I can use it again?

Comment: Does the computer recognize other SD cards? Does the SD card work in other computers?

Comment: Yes and I haven't tested it yet, will respond later

Comment: No, dosen't work on other PCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on OP's comments above, it sounds like the **SD card** has failed, not (as the title sort of implies) the SD card reader.

There's not really much you can do if a card/flash memory device simply won't be read.
If it's a new card it is probably a lemon; I would RMA it and get a replacement.